# ios ShareKit - facing "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" with the twiiter part

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I am using **ShareKit** in my iOS App . I have set everything properly in my config.h file . When I tested the App it was working fine but when I tried send tweets from the App i got error saying  "**read only applications can not send post data**" . Then I changed the access of the app on twitter . Now I am getting an error saying "**tokenRequestTicket Response Body: Failed to validate oauth signature and token**"

please tell me where I am doing wrong !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue . I just recreated the keys ( consumer and the secret ). And it resolved the issue . If any one faces this kinda issue , try re-generating the keys .